# Put commas in input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having an issue with commas and values.

I have a value that keeps changing all the time from checkboxes, sliding from jQuery ui slider and keyup functions.  I want to add commas to the total that is being changed each time rather than building it into each function.  If I have to build it into each function, I am not opposed to that either though.  The end value just needs to have commas in it.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZSeHU/

Any thoughts here?

Comment: If you're gonna down vote, unless give me the courtesy to tell me why rather than just doing it.  I see no reason for a down vote here.

Comment: you should always post your code in case the link dies. Disclaimer: what I am saying might NOT be the total or partial reason of why they are downvoting

Comment: I've seen many threads in the same structure as mine.  Down voting someone for posting a link to the code and structuring a proper question shouldn't happen.  That's just bad form.

Comment: @Sethem I was just pointing out that is not a good idea. But remember that this might not be the reason of the downvotes (read my disclaimer again)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `$("#increasedRevenueValue").val(value)` with `setIncRevenueValue(value)`

Inside, use

```
$("#increasedRevenueValue").val('$'+addCommas(value));
```

where addCommas is the following function:

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

This is the source: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html